# Replace all with special character doesn't work in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string

```
var str = "{CPARTY_&lt;BPARTY+_DPARTY}";
```

I need to find all occurences of below string (find) in main string(str).

```
 var find = "{CPARTY_&lt;BPARTY+_DPARTY}";
```

and replace it with below string.

```
var replace = "<span><div  ng-click='myClick($event)' title='null' data-token='CPARTY_<BPARTY+_DPARTY'  style='display: inline;'>{CPARTY_&lt;BPARTY+_DPARTY}</div></span>";
```

This doesn't work. That means no replacement done. No exception thrown.

```
str = str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
```

This works.

```
str = str.replace(find, replace);
```

I want to use the replace all syntax.I have realized that it has something to do with special characters < and $lt; If I don't have < and $lt; , there is no issue. I know it's something very silly but can't figure it out.

jsFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/848c1as4/9/

Comment: Escaping those characters might work

Comment: The string you pass into `new RegExp` has to be a valid regular expression. What you have right now is actually a valid regex, it just doesn't match your string. As @Randy mentions, escaping characters used in regular expressions is key.

Comment: @Mike McCaughan - I didn't understand when you said that my regex doesn't match my string. Str and find are exactly same.

Comment: `{` and `}` have special meaning in regular expressions.  They don't match the same characters from your string.  Same thing with `+`

Comment: What @Amy said :), also +, $, ^, ... See [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Special_characters_meaning_in_regular_expressions) for a list.

Comment: This actually works as replace-all :) `str = str.split(find).join(replace);`

Comment: Thanks Randy , Mike and Amy :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several characters have special meanings in regex. For example, `+` and `(`. You'll have to treat them before using it in RegExp, by *escaping* them.

```
var str = "{CPARTY_&lt;BPARTY+_DPARTY}";
var find = "{CPARTY_&lt;BPARTY+_DPARTY}";
var safeFind = find.replace(/([\/\,\!\\\^\$\{\}\[\]\(\)\.\*\+\?\|\<\>\-\&])/g,"\\$&");
var replace = "<span><div  ng-click='myClick($event)' title='null' data-token='CPARTY_<BPARTY+_DPARTY'  style='display: inline;'>{CPARTY_&lt;BPARTY+_DPARTY}</div></span>";
str = str.replace(new RegExp(safeFind, 'g'), replace);
```

([source](http://dumpsite.com/forum/index.php?topic=4.msg8#msg8))

Comment: I'm stealing this. Thanks!

Comment: Oh my, that regex.  No.  No no no no.

Comment: What do you recommend?

Comment: Joe - This solved my issues. Thanks! Is it a good practice to use such big regex in production code? Do we have another way to do this?

Comment: Depends how frequently it is used, and how many search strings exist. If `"{CPARTY_&lt;BPARTY+_DPARTY}"` is one of very few possible search strings, and you know them in advance, you can precompile the regexes and cache them, it'll be fast. If it's user input or you can't control how many exist, then this will indeed be slow.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the regular expression see how [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript). Or use a `split` `join` combo as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript) like this:

```
str = str.split(find).join(replace);
```